# Erase lines on canvas that has Bitmap as background

Tags: android, bitmap, line, android-canvas, erase

I am working on an Android app that has a Canvas that is created using the new Canvas(bitmap) function that the user can draw on using their finger.  The problem I am having is I can't find a way to allow the user to erase lines using their finger.  I have searched Google and looked at the sample FingerPaint app but the way they erase lines using:

```
setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

Only seems to work with a solid color for a Canvas.  I have written code to perform a undo/redo feature but it would be nice to be able to just erase part of the line instead of undoing allot of changes.  If anyone has any ideas I could try I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void resetBitmapCanvasAndPath() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mDrawingUtilities.mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH,Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT ,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        //Log.d("BITMAP","Restoring...");
        //mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length); 

    mDrawingUtilities.mCanvas = new Canvas(mDrawingUtilities.mBitmap);

    mDrawingUtilities.mPath = new Path();
}
```

reset the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky but a solution :).

in erease mode your bitmap fill color maybe same as background color(for example white).
user can draw with background color,so it is like deleting. :) (DrawSomething does like that).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Do you have an example on how to change an existing bitmaps background color?  I did some searching but all the things I found sound like they will erase or cover the image of the bitmap.

Comment: what is your app's background color?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment.  The main LinearLayout color is white.  The canvas is in the middle half of the screen and the bitmap that I create it with is a .png picture file that I convert to a bitmap.  I would be happy to try any ideas you have.

Comment: when user click's erease button you draw bitmap with white color(background color of main layout). user feel erease, but it is draw white (background color). It is like illusion. (:

Comment: I set the canvas to white and the path color to white but it still just draws white lines on the image.  Part of the problem could be that I have a undo/redo function where I save the line draws and redraw.  Maybe with this type of design this isn't possible.  My other thought was if I could make the canvas transparent and put the bitmap under it and just change the path color to Color.transparent when the user chooses erase. Any thoughts on this idea?

Comment: Hey Chris, I know it's been ages -- wondering if you figured it out? I have the exact same use case (a list of lines rendered on a transparent canvas atop an image) and am trying to erase parts of them with no luck so far. It looks like https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html#DST_OUT *should* do what I need but it doesn't work, only draws black pixels instead. :-( Did you ever solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's as easy as setting the alpha channel of the affected pixels to transparent. I forget if that's 0 or 255 since it changes depending on platform.

Comment: I tried setting the path to Color.Transparent but that did not work.

Comment: Ah. Is that coloring a drawing object? If so, it's like you are drawing with invisible ink

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can put SetXfermode() to use:

```
        if (view.getId()== R.id.erase_btn){  erase_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onDraw.setErase(true);
            }
        }


 public void setErase(boolean isErase){
    erase=isErase;
    if(erase) drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    else drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
}
```

which will help you remove the contents on your canvas following the finger.